# Как правильно переопределить hashcode для класса в котором, есть лишь одно поле типа Collection?

Tags: java, hashcode

Требуется чтобы класс мог выступать в качестве ключа для `HashMap`, для этого нужно переопределить его методы `hashcode` и `equals`,так чтобы выполнялся контракт между данными переопределенными методами.
Проблема в том что в классе есть лишь одно поле типа ArrayList.

Примиер:

```
    public class ObjectBox {

 List collection;
/**
 * Instantiates a new Object box.
 */
public ObjectBox() {
    this.collection = new ArrayList<>();
}

ObjectBox(final Object[] array) {
    collection = Arrays.asList(array);
    Collections.sort(collection);
}


/**
 * Add a new Element to Collection
 *
 * @param o the Object
 */
public void add(final Object o){
    collection.add(o);
}

/**
 * Deletes a given Object
 * in existing Data
 *
 * @param o the Object
 */
public void delete(final Object o){
    collection.remove(o);
}

//TODO
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}

//TODO
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}
```

}

будет ли правильным если я переопределю метод данным образом:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 31;
    result = 17 * result + (collection != null ? collection.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ObjectBox будет ключом в HashMap то никак не будет правильно. Ключи должны быть неизменяемыми/имутабельными, что в приведенном коде не соблюдается. После модификации ключа и, как следствие, изменении hashCode этот ключ уже не будет найден в HashMap.

При добавлении нового элемента в HashSet или добавлении пары ключ-значение в HashMap значение hashCode используется для нахождения "корзины" (ориг. bucket) в которую будет размещена ссылка на объект. При поиске объекта hashCode опять будет использован но уже для нахождения "корзины" в которой должен оказаться объект, после чего все объекты в "корзине" будут сравнены с искомым объектом посредством метода equals. Поэтому изменение hashCode приведет к тому, что поиск элемента будет происходить в другой "корзине" и совпадений не будет найдено, что будет явятся источником ошибки в логике работы программы. При этом ссылка на объект будет присутствовать в HashMap/Set из-за чего GC его не удалит, а это уже приведет к утечки памяти.

Демонстрация ошибки:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

    static class Key {

        private List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            } else if (other instanceof Key) {
                return Objects.equals(((Key) other).sequence, sequence);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(sequence);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Key(hash=" + hashCode() + ", seq=" + Arrays.toString(sequence.toArray()) + ")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Key key = new Key();
        key.sequence.add(10);
        key.sequence.add(20);

        System.out.println(key);

        Map<Key, String> keyValMap = new HashMap<>();
        keyValMap.put(key, "Эта штука навсегда затеряется где-то в недрах HashMap");
        System.out.println(keyValMap.get(key));

        key.sequence.add(30); // меняем hashCode
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(keyValMap.get(key) + " <= Где значение? Куда оно делось?!!!!!!");

        key.sequence.remove(2); // восстанавливаем hashCode
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(keyValMap.get(key) + " <= А вот же оно!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте проще:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(collection);
}
```

Под капотом будет примерно следующее:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    if (collection == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 31;

    for (Object element : collection)
        result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

    return result;
}
```